# I'm getting cursor = connection.cursor() NameError: name 'connection' is not defined error

Tags: python, cursor, psycopg2

Below is my code

```
psycopg2.connect('dbname=example user=user host=localhost password=pass')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE table2 (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT False
    );
 ''')

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table2 (id, completed) VALUES (1, true);')

connection.commit()

connection.close()
cursor.close()
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 5, in 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
NameError: name 'connection' is not defined**

I have tried everything I could find and nothing works. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close, it needs to be something like this:

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=rds_host,
                            user=name,
                            password=password,
                            database=db_name)
```

The way you have it you're passing in a string of all the values in it, no string just match individual attributes within the `.connect()` call

You can change `conn` to what you prefer.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much.